# How to Support Two Phase Commit for a pro*c application which get used by an external java application via JNI calls?

Tags: java, c, oracle, xa

Came through oracle XA, which provides an interface and can be used with Pro*c.
Another using application which uses this C application via JNI calls but how the transaction will be managed globally, who will act as resource manager, transaction manager if the middle-ware is the weblogic?

Answer (score 0):

If you use xa, an external transaction manager will be used. In your case it will have to use the web logic transaction manager.